# Creating online web interface to store messages in dB and make available to an end user, use PHP / MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql, oracle, forms, messaging

I've been approached about writing a system for a client.  They currently want something to replace  the email approach that is currently being used.

The system is fairly simple on the surface.  There is my client, who is the customer, and his clients.

His clients need to be able to create new messages which are then saved in a repository so to speak.  They can also edit and delete their messages.

My client should be able to view all the messages for him (so he can process them so to speak) and essentially be able to view them, filter them through advanced filters / search criteria, through a smart looking web front-end.

My main experience in this kind of thing is using PHP/MYSQL/Oracle.  I can see that it is quite easy to create a system for this using these technologies.  One dB, which will have aroound 20,000 records created per year say.  Allow access to my client to view, advanced filtering and searching, and to his clients to create, edit and delete.

I'm just wondering if I'm missing anything obvious here, in terms of an off-the-shelf solution?  Or should I be considering some other technologies (I pretty much can use anything I have to).

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

There are a multitude of options. I don't think any of them is better than the others for your application. I'd go with what you already know, or what you can hire people easily to create/maintain.

Comment: Thank you Jay.  I agree, I will go with what I know.